# Correct use of transactions in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, transactions

I have 2 commands and need both of them executed correctly or none of them executed. So I think I need a transaction, but I don't know how to use it correctly.

What's the problem with the following script?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION [Tran1]

INSERT INTO [Test].[dbo].[T1]
    ([Title], [AVG])
VALUES ('Tidd130', 130), ('Tidd230', 230)

UPDATE [Test].[dbo].[T1]
  SET [Title] = N'az2' ,[AVG] = 1
  WHERE [dbo].[T1].[Title] = N'az'

COMMIT TRANSACTION [Tran1]
GO
```

The `INSERT` command is executed, but the `UPDATE` command has a problem.

How can I implement this to rollback both commands if any of them have an error in execution?

Answer (score 639, accepted):

Add a try/catch block, if the transaction succeeds it will commit the changes, if the transaction fails the transaction is rolled back:

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION [Tran1]

  BEGIN TRY

      INSERT INTO [Test].[dbo].[T1] ([Title], [AVG])
      VALUES ('Tidd130', 130), ('Tidd230', 230)

      UPDATE [Test].[dbo].[T1]
      SET [Title] = N'az2' ,[AVG] = 1
      WHERE [dbo].[T1].[Title] = N'az'

      COMMIT TRANSACTION [Tran1]

  END TRY

  BEGIN CATCH

      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [Tran1]

  END CATCH
```

Comment: Shouldn't `BEGIN TRANSACTION [Tran1]` be placed inside `TRY`? Anyway - very simple and elegant piece of code.

Comment: @PiotrNawrot No, if the transaction creation failed there is no need to rollback it in the catch.

Comment: If you want to see the error, then include this in the catch:
`SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;`

Comment: @KevinLeStarge or simply `THROW;` if you're using SQL Server >= 2012 as mentioned [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/144814/184793)

Comment: If one wants a "visually nested syntax" so to say, i.e. such that `begin transaction` is nested under `begin try`, then a condition should be added before `rollback transaction`, which is: `if @@trancount > 0`.

Answer (score 132):

At the beginning of stored procedure one should put [`SET XACT_ABORT ON`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx) to instruct Sql Server to automatically rollback transaction in case of error. If ommited or set to OFF one needs to test [@@ERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933181%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) after each statement or use [TRY ... CATCH rollback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) block.

Comment: In other words, your transaction is not atomic unless you SET XACT_ABORT ON first.

Comment: Note - For XACT_ABORT: OFF is the default setting in a T-SQL statement, while ON is the default setting in a trigger

Comment: Just a clarification please, ¿ SET XACT_ABORT ON applies only for the current procedure?

Comment: @U.Busto Current transaction, yes.

Answer (score 46):

Easy approach:

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
    C [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
);

SET XACT_ABORT ON -- Turns on rollback if T-SQL statement raises a run-time error.
SELECT * FROM T; -- Check before.
BEGIN TRAN
    INSERT INTO T VALUES ('A');
    INSERT INTO T VALUES ('B');
    INSERT INTO T VALUES ('B');
    INSERT INTO T VALUES ('C');
COMMIT TRAN
SELECT * FROM T; -- Check after.
DELETE T;
```