# query rollback policies in sql server 2008 r2

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query that consists of some inserts and updates, something like this

```
   Insert Into #TempTable (...) Select top (1000) * from T where ....

   Update T2 Set c1=...,c2=... where w1

   Update T2 Set c1=...,c2=... where w2

   Update T2 Set c1=...,c2=... where w2
```

I run this query from a C# App. Each part of this query could be got time out because of heavy load on server, I wanna know that if one part of query got time out (for example second update), all prior queries (Insert and first update) would be rollback by Sql Server engine?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153648/correct-use-of-transactions-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: @raman: no, it's not. i don't want to use transaction

Comment: @user1121366 You cannot do a rollback without using a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

After opening the SqlConnection at your code, do `SqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;`, This will prevent timeout errors causing by .net C# side.

If you are creating SqlDataAdapter by using the sqlcommand you set the timeout to 0, make sure that: `SqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout=0` after creation by debugging.