# How to rollback database when user abort process?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have createde a stored procedure such as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE backupDB
BEGIN
...
exec('BACKUP DATABASE '+@targetDbName+' TO DISK = ''C:\ABC\'+@backupFileName+'.bak''')
...
END
```

I would like to rollback database when user abort backup Database process. For example, I create a button named "Cancel" and when user click it, all process in procedure 'backupDB' will be rollolbacked.
So, How can do it?
I use MS SQL Server 2008 R2 and Visual studio 2013 with ASP.NET MVC 5.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use try/catch plus transactions: <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153648/correct-use-of-transactions-in-sql-server-2008">Correct use of transactions in SQL Server 2008</a>

Answer (score 0):

You can apply Transaction in C# code or inside your stored procedure.[Transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224689/transactions-in-net)