# SqlKata Transactions

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, transactions, sqlkata

I am looking to use SqlKata for a project. However, part of the project criteria is that queries should be able to be carried out as transactions. Is there a way I can perform a query or multiple queries with MSSQL transactions?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

SQLKata uses `Dapper` as part of the execution of queries. Since [Dapper supports transactionScopes](https://dapper-tutorial.net/transaction), you can wrap your SQL Kata queries in transactions as well

```
 using System.Transactions;
....
       using (var scope = _db.Connection.BeginTransaction())
       {
            _db.Query("Posts").WhereNull("AuthorId").AsUpdate(new {
               AuthorId = 10
           });
           ...
            scope.Commit();

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

currently, there is no direct support for transactions in Sqlkata, it's planned in the near future, 
for now, you can invoke transactions directly using the `db.Statement()` method.

```
db.Statement("BEGIN TRANSACTION");

db.Query("Transactions").Where(...).Update(new {Amount = 100});
db.Query("...").Delete();

if(err) {

    db.Statement("ROLLBACK TRANSACTION");

}

db.Statement("COMMIT TRANSACTION");
```

Comment: Thank you for you response. However, when I try invoke transactions directly using the db.Statement() method, I get the following error: 'The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.'

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153648/correct-use-of-transactions-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: I have this, however I get the following error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'BEGIN'.' on the BEGIN TRY
`
db.Statement("BEGIN TRANSACTION");
                db.Statement("BEGIN TRY");

                db.Query("Customers").Insert(...);

            db.Statement("END TRY");
                db.Statement("BEGIN CATCH");
                    db.Statement("ROLLBACK TRANSACTION");
                db.Statement("END CATCH");
            db.Statement("COMMIT TRANSACTION");`

Comment: Does SqlKata use a new connection foreach query?