# What's the point of try-catch before a transaction if you're only rolling back?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions

As far as I know if you open an SQL transaction and an error occurs within it it will rollback automatically.

So, is there any point to putting a transaction in a try-catch block like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056973/tsql-try-catch-within-transaction-or-vice-versa) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153648/correct-use-of-transactions-in-sql-server).

Furthermore would `set xact_abort on` render the try-catch block obsolete in any case?

Comment: Unfortunately, "if an error occurs it will rollback automatically" is absolutely not always true. Whether or not a rollback will happen depends on the kind of error, and whether any more statements will be executed (despite the transaction already being doomed) likewise depends. See [Erland Sommarskog's excellent writeup on these matters](http://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html). `SET XACT_ABORT ON` is often very helpful to simplify error handling, as is managing the transaction client-side (since there it typically is a hard guarantee that any error produces a rollback).

Comment: Yes, I would keep the try-catch and rollback the transaction in the catch block. Guaranteed to rollback if there is an error and you can raise an error in the catch block.

Comment: @WesleyNightingale, does `set xact_abort on` do the same thing as the try-catch block in this case?

Comment: @JeroenMostert, thanks, but does that mean that using `set xact_abort on` is the same as a try-catch in this case?

Comment: No. *Most* errors that happen under `XACT_ABORT ON` rollback (certainly more than under `OFF`), but not all. See [here](http://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html#classification) (still from Erland's articles) for the details. Best results are obtained using *both* `XACT_ABORT ON` *and* `TRY .. CATCH`.

Comment: You can also do different things in the catch block (log to a table with specific info, exec sp, etc.)