# Ensure Successful INSERT before triggering DELETE

Tags: sql, sql-server

Am currently working on archiving a database, I have come up with a simple approach. However, executing the script can run into errors. Leading to a case where the insert is not successfully executed but the delete. Which means I delete records from production before inserting them into archive. Is there a way to ensure delete statement would not be executed unless insert is run successfully?

```
INSERT INTO [archive].[dbo].[Table]
SELECT *
FROM [Production].[dbo].[Table]
WHERE TimeStamp < DATEADD(year,-2,SYSDATETIME()) 

DELETE FROM [Production].[dbo].[table]
WHERE TimeStamp < DATEADD(year,-2,SYSDATETIME())
```

Comment: you can put a commit statement after the insert statement and then use delete.

Comment: are you using php ?

Comment: no, am not using PHP

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153648/correct-use-of-transactions-in-sql-server) might help

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to an explict transaction, one can specify an `OUTPUT` clause on the `DELETE` to perform the operation as a single autocommit transaction. This will ensure all-or-none behavior.

```
DELETE [Production].[dbo].[Table]
OUTPUT DELETED.*   
INTO [archive].[dbo].[Table]
WHERE TimeStamp < DATEADD(year,-2,SYSDATETIME());
```

Also, consider an explict column list instead of `*`.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would create a transaction, making the operation into a single update.

```
BEGIN TRAN

BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO [archive].[dbo].[Table] 
    SELECT * FROM [Production].[dbo].[Table] WHERE TimeStamp < 
             DATEADD(year,-2,SYSDATETIME())

    DELETE FROM [Production].[dbo].[table] 
    WHERE TimeStamp < DATEADD(year,-2,SYSDATETIME())

    COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   ROLLBACK
END CATCH
```

Basically, the code says.

- BEGIN TRAN - Start a group of commands that either all complete or
  none complete
- BEGIN TRY - Commands to try
- COMMIT - If I reach here, everything worked OK
- BEGIN CATCH
- ROLLBACK If an error occurs, roll back the commands (basically ignore
  them)

You should probably add some status to indicate success or failure, and maybe capture the error in the BEGIN CATCH block, but this should give you enough to get started

A second approach is to modify your DELETE statement a bit

```
DELETE FROM [Production].[dbo].[table] 
    WHERE TimeStamp IN (SELECT TimeStamp FROM [archive].[dbo].[Table])
```

Good luck

Comment: I suggest catch block `IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;THROW;` to raise an error instead of silently ignoring it. It's also a good idea to specify `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` to ensure the explict transaction is rolled back immediately should a client query timeout occur since the catch block code will not execute in that case.

Comment: Fully agree, the error from the BEGIN CATCH should  not be ignored.   How it is captured is something the developer needs to consider...   Thanks for the comments